# Get data from 3rd table

Tags: mysql

I got 3 tabels:

- wp_posts
- wp_metadata
- users

When I get my query from "**wp_posts**" i'm using **LEFT JOIN** to get the data from the "**wp_metadata**", but how can I get a value from the 3rd table "**users**"?

Example:
I have one post on my wordpressblog. On that post I have some meta-fields - one of them is called "**userid**". My users is located in a table outside of wordpress. How can I get the users username from the table "**users**" where the post-meta-key "**userid**" is equal to the "**users**"-tables row ID?

Here is my SQL-request as it is right now:

```
SELECT ID, post_title,
    post_excerpt, 
    post_content, 
    m.meta_value AS placeid, 
    i.meta_value AS photoid, 
    r.meta_value AS rating, 
    u.meta_value AS userid, 
    b.username 
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (m.post_id = p.ID) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta i ON (i.post_id = p.ID) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta r ON (r.post_id = p.ID) 
JOIN wp_postmeta u ON (u.post_id = p.ID) 
LEFT JOIN brugere b ON (b.id = userid) 
WHERE m.meta_key = 'placeid' 
AND i.meta_key = 'photoid' 
AND r.meta_key = 'rating' 
AND u.meta_key = 'userid' 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 50;
```

I want ONE query, because i'm using the query on a "**print json_encode**".

Comment: Here is a try to move the WHEREs to ON: `LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (m.post_id = p.ID) WHERE m.meta_key = 'placeid'` but no result. I also tried to change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN but also without effect.

Comment: Okay, now I get some results! But how do I get the b.username. My code with `LEFT JOIN brugere b ON (b.id = userid)` or `LEFT JOIN brugere b ON (b.id = u.meta_value)` dosen't work. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: @strawberry Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ce9a/2

Comment: Natural key? I don't understand. The wp_posts.ID refers to wp_postmeta.post_id and the wp_postmeta.value (where wp_postmeta.key is "userid") refers to brugere.id - and from this table I wont to get the brugere.username and print it in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.* 
     , x.placeid
     , x.photoid
     , x.userid
     , x.rating
     , u.username
  FROM wp_posts p
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT post_id
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'placeid' THEN meta_value END) placeid
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'photoid'  THEN meta_value END) photoid
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'userid'  THEN meta_value END) userid
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'rating'  THEN meta_value END) rating
         FROM wp_postmeta
        GROUP
           BY post_id
     ) x 
    ON x.post_id = p.id
  LEFT
  JOIN brugere u
    ON u.id = x.userid;

+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+
| ID | post_content | post_title   | post_excerpt   | post_status | post_type | placeid | photoid | userid | rating | username |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1 | Content 1    | Post title 1 | Post ecxerpt 1 | publish     | post      | 101     | 102     | 2      | 4      | Bruger 2 |
|  2 | Content 2    | Post title 2 | Post ecxerpt 2 | publish     | post      | 201     | 202     | 3      | 3      | Bruger 3 |
|  3 | Content 3    | Post title 3 | Post ecxerpt 3 | publish     | post      | 301     | 302     | 3      | 2      | Bruger 3 |
|  4 | Content 4    | Post title 4 | Post ecxerpt 4 | publish     | post      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     |
|  5 | Content 5    | Post title 5 | Post ecxerpt 5 | publish     | post      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f517a/10

Comment: Sorry, wrong id's - now I had change the post_id. There should be 3 posts in wp_posts 1, 2 and 3 - and all of them had 4 fields in wp_postmeta (placeid, photoid, userid, rating).

Comment: The fiddle is the same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f517a/1 (I already have updated it) :)

Comment: Great - I will look closer and test it later, thanks. I'll be back.

Comment: I think it' works - but how can I place a WHERE: `WHERE p.post_status = 'public'`- it will be nice if I could give the result a filter :)

Comment: Thanks my friend, it works! Thanks a lot for your help and to teach me to better MySQL work :)